# Use Gon in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, gon

Before upgrading to rails 5 I had `include Gon::GonHelpers` in my model file. Now I get an error and I am not able to use the `gon` variable in my model.

I get the error message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `gon' for ....
```

How can I get to use gon in my model?
I have found many answers on how to include it in views and controller, but not in models. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding:   `include Gon::ControllerHelpers`  seems to solve the problem